# How to print the text between the first occurence of a pair of strings?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, openssl

I'm trying to filter a part of a file that holds 2 digital certificates. Basically, I want the first part (let's say Cert1) and not the second part (Cert2).

Content of the file is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
AAAA
AAAA
ETC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
AAAA
AAAA
ETC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I was under the impression that this would give me the content of Cert1 *(the first part between the first BEGIN and the first END)*:

```
cat /etc/nginx/cert.pem | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

For some reason, though, it still presents me all the content between the second BEGIN and the second END *(basically, nothing changes; all content is the same)*.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following sed command for this task

```
sed '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/q' /etc/nginx/cert.pem
```

`q` is an exit code which instructs sed to quit. Therefore sed will print from the beginning of the file and quit when the pattern '-----END CERTIFICATE-----' is encountered. This causes it to stop at the end of the first certificate.

Also there is no need to use a pipe to redirect the output of cat to sed. Simply specify the filename in the sed command.

Source - http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/09/sed-selective-printing.html

Answer (score 8):

You were almost there:

```
sed -ne '
   /-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p      # got the range, ok
   /-END CERTIFICATE-/q                            # bailing out soon as the cert end seen
' /etc/nginx/cert.pem
```

But note that the cert begin and end marker lines are part of the output as well.