# How to print the text after the first occurence of a "start pattern"-"stop pattern" pair?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file that contains a bunch of certificates:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BBBBBBB
BBBBBBB
BBBBBBB
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CCCCCCC
CCCCCCC
CCCCCCC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to chop the one that said `A` in it and just have the `B` `C` ... `n` certificates.

It's very similar to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362031/how-to-print-the-text-between-the-first-occurence-of-a-pair-of-strings) and I was hoping for a portable way to do this. Preferbly with `sed` if possible but `awk` works too if it's not possible to do with `sed`.

Is there a way to make sed print until a particular value EXCEPT for the first occurrence?

Comment: Welcome to the site. The answer to your question depends somewhat on the circumstances. If your problem in quesion is indeed a well-structured certificate file as shown in your example, the solution is pretty straight-forward. If not: can the "starting" pattern (here: `BEGIN CERTIFICATE`) occur without a corresponding closing "end pattern" (`END CERTIFICATE`)? If so, what would you want the solution to do?

Comment: Why not just `sed '1,/END CERT/d'`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sounds like a good answer to me, why not post it (perhaps along with some explanation for the `sed` novice)? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AdminBee answer is the right way of doing that, but if you're sure that the section to omit is the **first** you can do that with `sed` as well :

```
sed -n '/^-*END CERTIFICATE-*$/!d;:a n;p;ba' file
```

Or in a multiline portable fashion :

```
sed -n '
    /^-*END CERTIFICATE-*$/!d;:a
    n;p;ba
' file
```

This `sed` deletes all lines till the first `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` found, then create a loop which will eat and print all the other lines.

Comment: Ah that is more succinct, and possibly portable too.

Comment: As it was my preference to do this with `sed` and i can be sure the first certificate is the one I want to omit, I'm going to mark this one as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If your input is a well-formed certificate file as shown in your example, the easiest way that comes to my mind is to do it with `awk`:

```
awk '$0=="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" {n++} n>1' test.cert
```

This will increase a counter variable `n` every time the current line (`$0`) matches exactly the "start pattern". It will print the current line if the "seemingly stray" boolean expression `n>1` is true, i.e. beginning with the second occurence of the start pattern. `awk` treats uninitialized variables as zero (or the empty string, depending on usage context), so there is no need to explicitly initialize `n` to `0` in a `BEGIN` section.

Things get more complicated if your input document can be corrupted, i.e. contain start patterns that are not correctly matched by end patterns and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, it will always be well formed as in the example, as it has come from openssl directly, ie `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443 < /dev/null 2>&1 > certificates.cert`

Comment: @dogman In that case the proposed answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the regex /BEGIN/  and /END/ to required.

```bsh
awk '
/BEGIN/,/END/{
  if ( /END/ && !f++ ) next
}f
' file
```

---

`perl` in slurp mode (`-0777`)

```bsh
perl -0777 -pe '
  my($b,$e) = map { quotemeta s/$/ CERTIFICATE/r } qw(BEGIN END);
  my($B,$E) = map { qr{^-+ $_ -+\n}mx } ($b,$e);
  my $re = qr{$B (?s:.*?) $E}mx;
  substr($_,0,$+[0],"") if m{$re}m;
' file
```

---

GNU sed editor

```bsh
sed -ne 's/\n//;t2
  /BEGIN/!{$!N;D;}
  :1;n;/END/!b1
  n
  :2;$!{N;P;G;D;}
  p
' file
```

---

The linux utility `csplit` can also be used here. We first chunk the input file around the END lines. Then delete the first file or first two in case an END appears before BEGiN.

```bsh
csplit -sz file '/END/+1' '{*}'
for f in xx*;do
  sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/!d;$Q1' $f
  status=$?; rm -- "$f"
  [ " $status" = ' 1' ] && break
done
printf '%s\n' xx* | xargs -r cat
```